# Find, group by, and calculate for weighted avg?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I didn't have a better title, so here goes.

I have a lookup table that shows me the distance between every `CityId` to every store. For example, the first row tells me that `H1` is 2.5 miles away from `Eagle`. It only shows the `H` sections, but it has every possible combination between `CityId` and store:

```
declare @stores table 
(
    CityId varchar(10),
    miles decimal(8,2),
    store varchar(30)
)
insert into @stores

select 'H1',2.5, 'Eagle' union
select 'H1',3.5, 'Sears' union
select 'H1',2.0, 'BK' union
select 'H2',2.0, 'Eagle' union
select 'H2',1.5, 'Sears' union
select 'H2',1.8, 'BK' union
select 'H3',0.1, 'Eagle' union
select 'H3',0.5, 'Sears' union
select 'H3',0.7, 'BK'
```

This is the data table. It has how many stores have left each section:

```
declare @gone table
(
    City varchar(10),
    CityId varchar(10),
    Outs int
)
insert into @gone 
select 'Houston', 'H1', 6  union 
select 'Houston','H2', 4  union
select 'Houston', 'H3', 1  union
select 'Miami', 'M1', 12  union
select 'Miami', 'M2', 10  union
select 'Miami', 'M3', 18 union
select 'Miami', 'M4', 15
```

To get the `weighted average` of `Eagle` in `Houston`, I have to get all rows where Houston is the city, multiply `@gone.Outs` by the distance, and divide by the sum of all the `Outs`.

For the `Houston - Eagle` combination, it would be:

> [((H1 to Eagle) * 6) + ((H2 to Eagle) * 4) + ((H3 to Eagle) * 1)]/(H1 Out + H2 Out + H3 Out)

which is:

> ((2.5*6) + (2.0*4) + (0.1*1))/(4+6+1) = 2.1 ('Eagle')

For the `Houston - Sears` combination, it would be:

> [((H1 to Sears) * 6) + ((H2 to Sears) * 4) + ((H3 to Sears) * 1)]/(H1 Out + H2 Out + H3 Out)

which is:

> ((6*3.5) + (4*1.5) + (1*0.5))/(4+6+1) = 2.5 ('Sears')

With Miami, it's the same thing:

> [((M1 to Sears) * 6) + ((M2 to Sears) * 4) + ((M3 to Sears) * 1) + ((M4 to Sears) * 1)]/(M1 Out + M2 Out + M3 Out + M4 Out)

The result should look like this:

```
City      Store    Avg
-----------------------
Houston   Eagle    2.1
Houston   Sears    2.5
Houston   BK       X.X
Miami     Eagle    X.X
Miami     Sears    X.X
Miami     BK       X.X
etc...
```

Well, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you already know the mathematical formulas you need to use, what exactly is your question?

Comment: How to join everything without using a `cursor`.

Comment: What is your desired result set?   You probably just need aggregate functions on CASE expressions.

Comment: I've added the result set.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select g.City, s.Store, sum(s.miles * g.Outs)/sum(g.Outs) as [Avg]
from @gone g
inner join @stores s on g.CityId = s.CityId
group by g.City, s.store
```

Comment: I offered the exact same solution, but it doesn't work; the join causes too many Outs to be counted.   This needs to be done with subqueries.

Comment: Yours grouped by `Store`, `CityID`, `City`, so not the exact same solution. Houston has 3 CityIDs for some reason (H1, H2, H3). Group by `City` and `Store` only solves this dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

Still untested, but I think this would do it:

```
SELECT City, Store, 
  SUM(miles*outs)/(SELECT SUM(outs) FROM @gone g2 WHERE g2.CityID=s.CityID) AS WeightedAverage
FROM @stores s
INNER JOIN @gone g
  ON s.CityID=g.CityID
GROUP BY Store, CityID, City
```

Comment: Using the example I posted, Houston should have 3 rows: `Houston - Eagle`, `Houston - BK`, `Houston - Sears`.